# How can I activate Tensorflow's XLA for the C API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I have built Tensorflow from source and I am using it's C API. So far everything works good, I am also using AVX / AVX2. My Tensorflow build from source was also built with XLA support. I now would like to also activate XLA (accelerated linear algebra) as I hope that it will once again increase the performance / speed during inference.

If I start my run right now I get this message:

```
2019-06-17 16:09:06.753737: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1541] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
```

On the official XLA homepage (https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/jit) I found this information about how to turn on jit on a session level:

```
# Config to turn on JIT compilation
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Here (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13853) it was explained how to set the TF_SetConfig in the C API. I was able to limit to one core before using the output of this Python code:

```
config1 = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'CPU':1})
serialized1 = config1.SerializeToString()
print(list(map(hex, serialized1)))
```

I implemented it as follows:

```
uint8_t intra_op_parallelism_threads = maxCores; // for operations that can be parallelized internally, such as matrix multiplication 
        uint8_t inter_op_parallelism_threads = maxCores; // for operations that are independent in your TensorFlow graph because there is no directed path between them in the dataflow graph
        uint8_t config[]={0x10,intra_op_parallelism_threads,0x28,inter_op_parallelism_threads};
        TF_SetConfig(sess_opts,config,sizeof(config),status);
```

Therefore I thought this would help out for the XLA activation:

```
config= tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1
output = config.SerializeToString()
print(list(map(hex, output)))
```

Implementation this time:

```
uint8_t config[]={0x52,0x4,0x1a,0x2,0x28,0x1};
        TF_SetConfig(sess_opts,config,sizeof(config),status);
```

However XLA still seems to be deactivated. Can somebody help me out with this issue? Or, if you once again have a loot at the warning:

```
2019-06-17 16:09:06.753737: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1541] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
```

Does that mean I have to set XLA_FLAGS during the build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out how to use XLA JIT, it is only available in the c_api_experimental.h Header. Just include this header and then use:

```
TF_EnableXLACompilation(sess_opts,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

@tre95 I have tried
`#include "c_api_experimental.h"
TF_SessionOptions* options = TF_NewSessionOptions();
TF_EnableXLACompilation(options,true);`
but it compiled failed with error **collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status** .However ,it can compile and run successfully if i do not do this.

Comment: the error is probably because you didn't build TF with XLA support, but it is still present in the header.

Answer (score 1):

For `tensorflow` CPU having version`1.14`, I have set value for environment variable `TF_XLA_FLAGS`with the value `--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit`, i.e

```
export TF_XLA_FLAGS = --tf_xla_cpu_global_jit
```

or on Linux

```
TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit
```

and it works for me. Alternatively,
It will also works if we set the `XLA_FLAGS` environment variable with the value `--xla_hlo_profile`, i.e

```
export XLA_FLAGS = --xla_hlo_profile
```

I hope it will also work for you to accelerate machine learning models by using Accelerated linear Algebra(XLA). Than you!